# How to use friend class in C++/CX?

Tags: windows-runtime, c++-cx

I need to access class A 's private member in class B 's function and I want to use friend class. however, it seems can not be used as the c++ way .

> "error C3816" class Class2 was previously declared or defined with a different WinRT modifier

How can I do to solve it?
P.S.: I can not write get/set function in public area, for I do not want class user to know private member .

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind *why* you'd declare a C++/CX *ref class*, it is to allow a program written in another language to use your C++ code.  Such a language will not have any notion of the *friend* keyword, it is highly specific to the C++ language.  Only a C++ compiler is capable of enforcing the friend contract.  And in fact will not work at all when, say, that client code is written in C#, the CLR strongly enforces accessibility.  Accordingly, the metadata format of the .winmd file that's generated by your project doesn't support expressing the notion of *friend* at all.  So the compiler doesn't either.

First check to make sure you are using C++/CX appropriately, only use the *ref class* keyword if you actually intended to make the class accessible to other languages.  Use a regular C++ class, plain *class* without the *ref* contextual keyword, if the class is only going to be used by your own code.  If it is truly intended to be used as an interop class then you will have no other option but to make the member public.

Comment: I build Windows Runtime Component project to wrap my sdk interface written by c++ for C# UI project to call for windows store , so I do need C++/CX to complete the work.

Comment: Now I know "friend" can not be used in C++/CX ,I had tried to use "map" to keep the relationship and it is seemed to work till now. Thanks for your Answer .

Comment: @Hanqing `friend` *can* be used in C++/CX, just not in a `ref class`.

Answer (score 0):

Access specifiers are precautionary to prevent accidental access and so std C++ & stl performance with specific select CX friends- for say holding xaml binding datacontext containers- is straightforward approach. For whichever reason, VC++ is racist w. r. t. WinRT ABI mingling through OOP. One known alternative is to switch to generative meta programming instead of OO. To do this, keep template member function in the class that wants to befriend the consumer, and specialize this in the scope of the consumer and then onwards use the specialized version from within the consumer. Its sort of hidden from Microsoft family friendship affair.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using

```
friend ref class Class2;
```

instead of

```
friend class Class2
```